# Call SSRS from ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have an SSRS Report Server Project Wizard in which I have created a Report named `ContractForm`.
Now I want to show that report from UI in the another project in asp using C#.

How will I do this?

So far I have tried using Microsoft Report Viewer. But I am getting this error:

```
"ServerReport.ReportPath could not find"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure of your report path, the easiest way to determine it is to browse to the report in your browser of choice, and examine the url. The ItemPath parameter of the query-string is the url encoded path to your report. It will look something like   `%2fSomeDir%2fMy+Report`, which decodes to `\SomeDir\My Report`.

On the other hand, you may have some other issue, but it's a bit difficult to tell from the information given.

Comment: can u give a fresh example how to call ssrs rdl report from aspx page using c#

Comment: Other way round - update your answer with what you've tried, and then I'll correct.